# how to get 'generator point' for Monero transaction

Tags: daemon

I am using get_transactions of daemon rpc to get specifics of a transaction.

Trying to check incoming transactions manually by checking this method :

`is_mine(out, R, i):
    P = Hs(8aR||i)G + B
    return P == out`

Credits to [jtgrassie](https://monero.stackexchange.com/users/7493/jtgrassie)

How do I get G from get_transactions?

Comment: `G` is not in the tx, it's a pre agreed upon generator point of the ed25519 curve. See [this q/a](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6050/what-is-the-base-point-g-from-the-whitepaper-and-how-is-it-represented-as-a) which explains further.

Comment: Does the coordinate, agreed upon, hold special meaning. Or is it totally random, that this point was chosen, and not a neighboring point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

G is {0x58, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66 }.

See src/ringct/rctOps.h, line 65.